# My App is not visible in the django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I have this code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from test_app.models import Master, Detail


class DetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Detail


class MasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]


admin.register(Master, MasterAdmin)
```

But somehow it does not get displayed in the django admin index page.

Other apps are listed, and their `admin.py` file looks similar.

What's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `admin.site.register(Master, MasterAdmin)`

---

#### Method-1

```
from django.contrib import admin
from test_app.models import Master, Detail


class DetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Detail


class MasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]


admin.site.register(Master, MasterAdmin)
```

#### Method-2 : using [`@register` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from test_app.models import Master, Detail


class DetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Detail


@admin.register(Master)
class MasterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [DetailInline]
```

Ref : [ModelAdmin objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)